# Android studio: When trying to put a button on, it is giving me a rendering error saying that

Tags: java, android

Im new to adroid studios. When adding a button it is giving me a rendering error saying that there is missing styles and is it the correct theme chosen for this layout. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You have to give more information. Post the error stack trace and the relevant code to start with.

Comment: Always post your code when asking question to show what you are already doing.

Comment: Have the same problem.  Best to code using command line.  Android Studio is a little buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have you're SDK platform installed correctly and when using Android Studio avoid incorrect XML formatting. It's best if you provide your XML code instead to see what's wrong.

Comment: What code? I literally havnt started coding anything yet, it wont let me put anything on to the design

Answer (score 0):

If the rendering error is just shown in the design view of a layout, but everything is working on a device/emulator, you can ignore it. The design view is not able to show all kinds of elements and themes.

Comment: It wont let me add any buttons or anything. I can basically do nothing

Comment: Create the layout per code on the "Text" view, not "Design". You'll need to learn this earlier or later, because that's how you build complex views in android. There are several tutorials on the internet (e.g. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-xml-layouts--mobile-12749).